# Why do gummy bears explode when added to hot potassium chlorate?

Tags: redox, combustion, carbohydrates

This [link](http://www.learnsomething.tips/6-incredible-chemical-reaction-gifs-6/) shows that a gummy bear explodes when in contact with heated potassium chlorate, $\ce{KClO3}$. But what in a gummy bear creates this reaction?

Also, do other foods (fruit, icing sugar...) react as violently with potassium chlorate?

[image: Gif of gummy bear explosion]

Comment: **Never, never, never repeat this experiment on your own.** Potassium chlorate is known to form mixture with violent and sensitive behavior with almost everything combustible and many incombustible things.

Comment: Also, be prepared to throw away the test tube afterwards.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[Potassium chlorate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Potassium_chlorate) is a source of oxygen. After heating, it decomposes to $\ce{O2}$ and $\ce{KCl}$:
$$\ce{4 KClO3 → KCl + 3 KClO4}$$
$$\ce{KClO4 → KCl + 2O2}$$

The gummy bear is mainly composed of sugar and other carbohydrates. Those carbohydrates will react with oxygen, [combustion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combustion#Chemical_equations) occurs. For example, glucose will react in this manner:
$$\ce{6O2 + C6H12O6 -> 6CO2 + 6H2O}$$

If there is any material present which does not burn, such as $\ce{H2O}$, the temperature will not rise as high. For gummy bears the reaction works spectacularly because they are mainly carbohydrates (>70%).

An apple, for example, has only ~13% carbohydrates – unless you dry it, of course. On the other hand, [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xXts1AlpR_g#t=36) on YouTube is an example of how sugar itself reacts violently with potassium chlorate.