# Smoke Bomb with Potassium Nitrate and Sucrose (Or is it caramel?)

Tags: everyday-chemistry, home-experiment

I've scoured the internet for a proper chemical reaction between caramelized sucrose and Potassium Nitrate for the past few days. So far, every chemical reaction I see drawn out is between pure sucrose and potassium nitrate, while the smoke bomb in question requires caramelized sucrose, an entirely different thing altogether that probably will give you a different reaction.

Am I over-thinking this, or is Caramelen/Caramelan the reactant, instead of sucrose? If someone could be so kind as to draw out the chemical equation between the two, that'd be awesome, too. (Heat is part of this equation, as the substance is lit to produce the smoke)

Comment: http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/22404/what-substance-in-a-gummy-bear-reacts-with-heated-potassium-chlorate-to-create-a

Comment: Caramel is, depending on how badly caramelised it was, either mostly sucrose, mostly carbon, or some badly-defined intermediate. And please don't try building a bomb if you don'tknow what you're doing. Or on second thought, just don't build a bomb.